# How to create an array of actions?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, winforms, delegates

I am writing a VB.NET Class, and I have run into the issue of needing to create an array of actions. How does one do that in VB.NET?

UPDATE: I am trying to write a collision detection class that stores objects to collide with, and functions to execute when the collision happens with indexes that line up the object to the function.

So like:

```
Class CDE
    Private Collidables As Windows.Forms.Control()
    Private Actions As 'Action Array
```

Comment: You should add the relevant code for the class and examples of how you would use it so everyone is clear on what you want.  Something this vague is likely to get DVed

Comment: this is why we like code: `and functions...` there is an [Action delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx) but it returns nothing, ie is for Subs.  If you really want a function, use [Func](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx).  However, I would bind the object/control with the specific method using a class.  Are the controls more specific ... like maybe  pictureboxes?

Comment: @Plutonix No. I want this to be able to be applied to ANY control (This is to be imported into all of my projects that require collision detection)

Comment: Then you probably need a CollisionItem class rather than parallel arrays.  The obvious problem is that they can be different sizes or bad code could put the delegate for (3) in (2) so the wrong control does the wrong thing.  Depending on the signatures, a plain delegate might work better,

Comment: @Plutonix what would the collisionitem class do? (As far as specifics go)

Comment: Associate a specific delegate with a specific control

Comment: OH. That makes more sense. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not enough info to provide a specific answer here, but you would create this array the same as you would create any other array in VB.NET.

```
Dim actionsArr = New MyAction() {action1, action2, action3, action4}
```

On a side note, I've always been more fond of using Lists over arrays.  It's much easier to add and modify items in a list.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385204.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much. That was exactly what I was looking for